# Int from for loop not working in function - JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am pretty new to Javascript and have noticed this odd issue come up.

```
    var dispatchMouseEvent = function(target, var_args) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        target.dispatchEvent(e);
    };

    var Level1Cats = document.getElementsByClassName("p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry "); //GETTING LEVEL 1 CATS

    var Level1CatsLen = Level1Cats.length; //GETTING LEVEL 1 CAT LEN

    for (i = 0; i <= Level1CatsLen-1; i++) {

        var ID1 = Level1Cats[i].id;
        var temp1 = Level1Cats[i].innerHTML;
        temp1.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&").replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");

        function GoToLevel2(callback) { //GO TO NEXT LEVEL!
        dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "mouseover", true, true);
        dispatchMouseEvent(Level1Cats[i], "click", true, true);
        }

        function GetLevel2() { //GET NEXT LEVEL
        var Level2Cats = document.getElementsByClassName("p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry");
        return Level2Cats.length;
        }

        setTimeout(function() { //RUN IT WITH TIMING
            GoToLevel2();
        }, 100);
        var Level2CatsLen = GetLevel2();
}
```

When the code is executed it gives me an error (Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined)
I know this is because the i in the function does not seem to work. If I simply replace it with an int value of 1 it will execute and click cat 1, 16 times, as expected..

I would have thought this should work, any ideas how I can work around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @Thilo love ya work :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, a closure `GoToLevel2` is created, closing over the variable `i`, when `i` is `1`. Then the loop runs through, `i` is incremented to `2`, and the loop is terminated.

Then your `setTimeout` fires after 100ms, and invokes your closure. It still remembers that there was once a variable `i`, but it now contains `2`. `Level1Cats[2]` is undefined, and you get an error.

The standard solution is to enclose the contents of the loop into another self-evaluating function that will not close over `i`:

```
for (i = 0; i <= Level1CatsLen-1; i++) {
    (function(i) {
         // ...
    })(i);
}
```

(Note also that `setTimeout(function() { GoToLevel2(); }, 200)` is identical to, but less efficient than `setTimeout(GoToLevel2, 200)`.)